# Check what java class type is this

Tags: java, reflection

I want to check `String` is interface or not using `Reflection` method `.isInterface`. Here is what I tried but it gives Class not found exception.

```
public class CheckingClassType {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("String");
            System.out.println(c.isInterface());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");`

You need to give the full package name of the class. The reflection needs to know that to instantiate the class name as multiple classes with same name can exist in different packages.